# How to get text from <Strong> tag using xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is my HTML code

```
<p>
<strong>Telephone:</strong>
 1(111)656-3485
<br/>
```

Comment: My HTML code is <p>
<strong>Telephone:</strong>
 1(111)656-3485
<br/>

Comment: i have tried with the this xpath but i am getting error while executing the script because of text() method in the xpath                        
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong/following-sibling::text()"));

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has functions to get the text from WebElements, you don't need to extract the text in your xpath. Use.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpaths to get it, Please find the code below:

```
WebElement eleText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Telephone:')]"));

String textTelephone=eleText.getText();
System.out.println(textTelephone);
```

You can use another xpath like that

```
WebElement eleText=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Telephone:')]"));

String textTelephone=eleText.getText();
System.out.println(textTelephone);
```